# Яндекс.Карты + Vue (vue-yandex-maps) + подключение модулей

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Пытаюсь воспроизвести вот этот [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_custom/) Яндекса по рисованию произвольной области на карте с помощью vue.js.

Использую [vue-yandex-maps](https://vue-yandex-maps.github.io/guide/). По самому подключению карт разобрался, но никак не могу понять, как подключить дополнительные модули, как в примере.
В примере модуль находится в файле paintOnMap.js, надо подключить его через import, но к моменту подключения ymaps не инициализирована и я получаю ошибку.

Прошу помочь с решением, гугл не помог мне решить задачу

[Песочница](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-ftc3so?file=/src/App.vue)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <yandex-map
          ref="map"
          :coords="[55.72, 37.65]"
          zoom="10"
          style="width: 100%; height: 600px"
          :controls="[]"
          @map-was-initialized="onInitMap"
        >
        </yandex-map>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { yandexMap } from "vue-yandex-maps";
    
    import './paintOnMap.js'
    
    export default {
      name: "App",
      components: {
        yandexMap,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          map: null,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        onInitMap(map) {
          this.map = map;
    
          // ymaps
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
    
    <style>
    </style>
```